# Query Builder new index for join

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a query builder:

```
$Metro = DB::table('fijacion')->where('tipo','Metro')->join('adp', 'fijacion.id', '=', "adp.id_fijacion")->get();
```

It returns me some records where id is not sequential ie
1 5 6 14 etc.

> $Metro not sequential

I relate that query to another one if it has the sequential values 0 1 2 3 4 etc.

> $Metro[] is a sequential

```
foreach($Metrop as $Metro){
    $array = explode("|", $Metro->nr);
    $Metro = DB::table('fijacion')->where('tipo','Metro')->join('adp', 'fijacion.id', '=', "adp.id_fijacion")->get();
    $MetroA[] = DB::table('users')
              ->select('*')
              ->whereIn('numero',$array)
              ->where('categoria', '<=', 3)
              ->join('puntos', 'users.numero', '=', "puntos.nr")
              ->orderby('categoria', 'asc')
              ->orderby('total', 'asc')
              ->get();
 }
```

What I need is to be able $ Meter to be sequential to join it with my other sentence.

```
@foreach($MetroA[($Metro->xxx)] as $item)

@endforeach
```

> $Metro->xxx is a sequential

That is not to be done

it's possible??

Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier if you use this:

```
@foreach($Metro as $i => $Metro)
    .....
@endforeach
```

This would do the job without any extra code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was easier than I thought

What I did was generate a routine with $ i

```
@php$
i = 0;
@endphp
```

and later

```
@foreach($Metro as $Metro)
 @php
  $i++;
 @endphp
.....
@endforech
```